# Using qiskit on mutiple cores

Tags: qiskit, programming

I would like to be able to set the number of cores the `AerSimulator` should be running. For now I've tried

```
backend = AerSimulator()
backend.set_options(max_parallel_threads=params['ncores'])
```

where `params['ncores']` is an `int` with the number of cores the simulator should run on.
I would expect that changing it from 1 to 4 the run time would change, but this is not the case. Can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although `max_parallel_threads`sets the maximum number of CPU cores used by OpenMP for parallelization during execution of an experiment, there are other factors that affect the amount of parallelization that will actually occur. Most notably, your circuit must have at least 14 qubits. You can control this value using `statevector_parallel_threshold` [`AerSimulator`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit_aer.AerSimulator.html)'s option.

---

The following example demonstrates how to take advantage of having multiple cores. Let's create 200 circuits:

```
from qiskit.circuit.random import random_circuit

num_circuits = 200
num_qubits = 20
depth = 30

circuits = []
for n in range(num_circuits):
    circuits.append(random_circuit(num_qubits, depth, max_operands = 2, measure = True))
```

Then we transpile them:

```
from qiskit import transpile
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator

backend = AerSimulator(method = 'statevector')

tr_circuits = transpile(circuits, backend = backend)
```

Now, we configure the backend for parallelization and run the circuits:

```
backend.set_options(
    max_parallel_threads = 0,
    max_parallel_experiments = 0,
    max_parallel_shots = 1,
    statevector_parallel_threshold = 16
)

result = backend.run(tr_circuits).result()
counts = result.get_counts()
```

Note that:

- `max_parallel_threads` equal 0 means use all the CPU cores.
- `max_parallel_experiments` equal 0 means maximum number of experiments that may be executed in parallel equals `max_parallel_threads` value.
- `max_parallel_shots` equal 1 means disable parallel shot execution.
- `statevector_parallel_threshold` equal 16 (default) means that number of qubits in the circuit must be greater than 16 to enable parallelization for matrix multiplication during execution. Note that enabling parallelization to small circuits can reduce performance.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I have multiple cores available and I want to run a set of say 200 circuits, how can I take advantage of having multiple cores? Using ``max_parallel_shots``?

Comment: I updated my answer to include a detailed example.

Comment: Many thanks for the added code! My question was more in the direction of how to take advantage of multiple cores in a situation where the circuit has less 16 qubits. (Even just 5).

Comment: Just change `statevector_parallel_threshold` to be 5. Note, however, that small qubits number *may* reduce performance instead of enhancing it because thread creation and context switching are not free. This overhead may take time longer than the computation itself.